# How to highlight today's date in telerik datepicker

Tags: asp.net, telerik

I need to highlight the today's date in **telerik datepicker**, I am developing a web page in that page at some point user needs to select the date from the calendar which i binned there,in that calendar I need today's date should be highlighted what can i do for that..?????
thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 datePicker.MinDate = DateTime.Today
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a SpecialDays tag to your datepicker
You can see how to do this here:
http://www.telerik.com/forums/raddatepicker---highlight-today-s-date

```
<telerik:RadDatePicker ID="RadDatePicker11" Skin="Vista" runat="server">  
<Calendar runat="server">  
<SpecialDays>  
<telerik:RadCalendarDay Repeatable="Today" ItemStyle-BackColor="Green">  
</telerik:RadCalendarDay>  
</SpecialDays>  
</Calendar>
```